# Ignore duplicate key error in MySQL on INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, key

I am trying to duplicate a row in my table, into another table. There query looks like this

```
INSERT INTO `quote_block_arc` (`id`,`quote_id`,`name`,`description`,`price`,`hours`,`days`,`total_hours`,`is_print`,`amends`) SELECT `id`,`quote_id`,`name`,`description`,`price`,`hours`,`days`,`total_hours`,`is_print`,`amends` FROM `quote_block` WHERE `quote_id` = '41'
```

However, it failing saving there is a duplicate key for this row, is there a way to ignore that warning and run the query?

Comment: Why would your want to have a duplicate key in your table? If you do not net the unique key remove the constraint in the schema. If you need the unique key, you will not want a duplicate key.

Comment: @cmmi - I'm not having duplicates, I'm inserting data from 1 table into another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occurs because you have specified one of the columns of your table to be `UNIQUE`. You cannot have 2 rows with the same value for this column. If you want to replace the existing row instead, use `REPLACE` instead of `INSERT`. If you really want rows containing the same value for the column, remove the `UNIQUE` modifier from that column.

Using `INSERT IGNORE` as described in some of the other answers will prevent the error being issued, but will not update the table.

Comment: I've looked into REPLACE, and it works well. However, some times i need to use REPLACE and other time I'll need INSERT, is there a way to do "REPLACE OR INSERT INTO"?

Comment: [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 5):

You can perform `INSERT IGNORE`, or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
Another way is to check result of the query, if it's false - check the error, and if the error code is 1062 (duplicate entry) to continue execution as if there were no error.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more on the second part are you saying about checking every key manually via select before inserting?

Answer (score 2):

try

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `quote_block_arc` (`id`,`quote_id`,`name`,`description`,`price`,`hours`,`days`,`total_hours`,`is_print`,`amends`) SELECT `id`,`quote_id`,`name`,`description`,`price`,`hours`,`days`,`total_hours`,`is_print`,`amends` FROM `quote_block` WHERE `quote_id` = '41'
```

Comment: This will *not* add the entry if there is duplicate key error.

Answer (score 1):

Having a duplicate row in a table with a unique/primary constraint would violate its integrity. You should check what the key is and confirm if you actually need to copy it. For example, AUTO_INCREMENT primary keys are traditionally not inserted because the database will fill that for you automatically. I'd check the destination table `quote_block_arc` if `id` is AUTO_INCREMENT. IF it is, remove it from the INSERT and let MySQL insert it by itself.

Using `INSERT IGNORE` will result in your row **not** being inserted. Use `REPLACE` if you want to overwrite the duplicate key, but I do not recommend it over the method I've described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

> @cmmi - I'm not having duplicates, I'm inserting data from 1 table into another.

I recommend you get the [highest](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) `id` from the target `quote_block_arc`, you then add that to the `id` in your `SELECT` subquery. That way, you know how to update any other related entries in other tables that reference those rows. If you were to let the RDBMS assign new `id`s for you, all relation would be lost.